# column height in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make column height shrink when it is displayed on smaller screen? I used bootstrap 3.3.7 . I made 3 columns inside a row and sat them to `col-md-2`, `col-md-9`, `col-md-1`. They are displayed correctly on md screen and bigger. On small screen they are still displayed fine. However, on small and extra small screen, I want to make first and third columns height shrink to the height of their contents.

Here is a part the HTML code and css I used:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-
    dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-
    dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="second_page.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2" id="first_left_column_box">
                <div class="left_content" id="first_left_column">
                    <a class="salehslist" id ="category" href="#" 
                         style="text-decoration:none;"> <center> content 
                         </center> </a>
                </div>
            <div>
                    <h1> another content </h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="breadcrumb">
                    <a id ="category" href="#" > <center> content </center> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1> many contents" nested rows and columns" are here</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1" id="last_right_column_box">
                <div class="right_content" id="last_right_column">
                    <div>
                        <h1> many contents </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
/* all a tags colors */
a { color: #4285F4; }

/* first left column */

#first_left_column_box{
    background-color: #eee;
  border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-right: 1px #ccc solid;
    height:200vh; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}
#first_left_column{
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;

}

/* middle column */

.breadcrumb {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* last right column */
#last_right_column_box{
  background-color: #eee;
    border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-right: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding: 10px;
    height:200vh; 
}
#last_right_column{
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Comment: you would need a media query for small screen sizes that overwrites your `height:200vh; ` with `height:auto` (or a media query to only apply that height for md screen size)

Comment: Or use bootstrap 4 if you are trying to get equal height columns, then you wouldn't need to put a height in at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use with col- with col-md:

.col- (extra small devices - screen width less than 576px)
.col-sm- (small devices - screen width equal to or greater than 576px)
.col-md- (medium devices - screen width equal to or greater than 768px)
.col-lg- (large devices - screen width equal to or greater than 992px)
.col-xl- (xlarge devices - screen width equal to or greater than 1200px)

try use col-2 and col-md-2 like example:

```
<div class="col-2 col-md-2" id="first_left_column_box">
```

Read this... can help you. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap currently doesn't support anything for automatic resizing of height of columns , we are bounded to use media queries so just use it !!

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Although your answer might be correct, the implied tone could be perceived as rude. Also, if you know how to fix OP's problem with media queries, why not suggest a code example to get him on his way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use media queries for the separate screens. You can write media queries like so

```
@media not|only mediatype and (expressions) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

but it is better to separate the rules which are applicable for the given rules, by creating separate CSS files for the separate sizes:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="mediatype and|not|only (expressions)" href="print.css">
```

An example for your case:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 699px)" href="small-screen.css">
```

And put here the rules for small screen. You can create separate CSS files for separate screen size categories.